# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' issue at json array

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I am trying to access json object from an array in swift 3.0, which gives no error when compiled for simulator but when i compile it again for generic devices it starts giving error on array **Ambiguous use of  'subscript'** i tried many solution but didn't succeeded, i am new to ios development can anyone solve my issue. here is code
Error is at line 3 after "?(here is the error)[0]"

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let result = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

            if let Response = result["Response"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                if let View = Response["View"]?[0] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let Result = View["Result"]?[0] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                        if let Location = Result["Location"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                            if let LinkInfo = Location["LinkInfo"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
```

here is the json i am trying to parse

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
        "Timestamp": "2017-07-02T08:58:17.016+0000",
        "NextPageInformation": "2"
    },
    "View": [
        {
            "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId": 0,
            "Result": [
                {
                    "Relevance": 1,
                    "Distance": 6,
}]}]}]
```

Comment: the code could be much much better by using Decodable protocol, in swift 4, but unfortunately you asked a solution in swift3.

Comment: Did you even search for "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'"?

Comment: Yes i did search it, and what i found was Type casting issue, i tried other Type casting classes but didnt succeeded,